# Method does not exist: org.elasticsearch.client.RequestOptions$Builder.setRequestConfig(Lorg/apache/http/client/config/RequestConfig;)

Tags: spring-boot, elasticsearch, hibernate-search-6

I am creating Hibernate Search 6 application with Spring Boot 2.3.4

I am facing this error while I try to build my application -

```
Description:

An attempt was made to call a method that does not exist. The attempt was made from the 
following location:

   org.hibernate.search.backend.elasticsearch.client.impl.ElasticsearchClientImpl.setPerRequestSocketTimeout(ElasticsearchClientImpl.java:198)

The following method did not exist:


org.elasticsearch.client.RequestOptions$Builder.setRequestConfig(Lorg/apache/http/client/config/RequestConfig;)Lorg/elasticsearch/client/RequestOptions$Builder;

The method's class, org.elasticsearch.client.RequestOptions$Builder, is available from the following locations:

jar:file:/C:/Users/pranali.rasal/.m2/repository/org/elasticsearch/client/elasticsearch-rest-client/7.6.2/elasticsearch-rest-client-7.6.2.jar!/org/elasticsearch/client/RequestOptions$Builder.class

The class hierarchy was loaded from the following locations:

org.elasticsearch.client.RequestOptions.Builder: 
file:/C:/Users/pranali.rasal/.m2/repository/org/elasticsearch/client/elasticsearch-rest-client/7.6.2/elasticsearch-rest-client-7.6.2.jar


Action:

Correct the classpath of your application so that it contains a single, compatible version of org.elasticsearch.client.RequestOptions$Builder
```

Following are the dependencies that i have added -

```
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.search</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-mapper-orm</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate.search</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-search-backend-elasticsearch</artifactId>
            <version>6.1.5.Final</version>
        </dependency>
```

Let me know if I missing something.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is all explained here: https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#gettingstarted-framework-spring-boot-dependency-versions

Basically, Spring Boot is managing your dependencies, and it's forcing an older version of the Elasticsearch client. You need to force it back to the version Hibernate Search expects (a newer version, 7.16.x).

---

And just to clarify, this has nothing to do with the Elasticsearch server version that I've seen mentioned in other answers. This is strictly about your client.

Comment: oh so spring is culprit here? that's what i was wondering about the server version, thanks

Answer (score 1):

This is probably due to incompatible version of the elasticsearch dependency. From https://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/stable/search/reference/en-US/html_single/#getting-started-compatibility it seems you need 7.10 or 7.16 but you have 7.6 dependency. Also check server version to be sure.

Comment: Hey, I am using elasticsearch 7 for server.

Comment: But which minor version of the server?

Answer (score 0):

> hibernate-search-backend-elasticsearch

is internally dependent on **elasticsearch-rest-client-7.6.2.jar**

And the method

> org.elasticsearch.client.RequestOptions$Builder.setRequestConfig(Lorg/apache/http/client/config/RequestConfig;)Lorg/elasticsearch/client/RequestOptions$Builder;

it is trying to find is in later versions of low level client.

Temporary solution will be to exclude 7.6.2 and include latest version of **elasticsearch-rest-client-7.6.2.jar** -

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.hibernate.search</groupId>
        <artifactId>hibernate-search-backend-elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <exclusions>
            <exclusion>
                <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
                <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
            </exclusion>
        </exclusions>
    </dependency>
```

and including,

```
       <dependency>
            <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
            <artifactId>elasticsearch-rest-client</artifactId>
            <version>7.10.0</version>
        </dependency>
```

Since this is a temporary, I am not sure if this is reliable.
Please let me know in case there is a better solution.

Comment: what is version of your elasticsearch ?

Comment: elasticsearch 7.0.0